# Should I to go the Nightmare Frontier?

Tags: bloodborne

I received the Tonsil Stone and could get myself caught by a lesser Amygdala to reach the Frontier. But on the wiki I use for reference it says: "From the point you spawn in the Lecture Building (1st floor), you will be unable to access the Nightmare of Mensis or the Lecture Building 2nd Floor." 
Does this mean I can't ever go to those locations or just for now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you arrive at the Lecture Building (1st floor) via Tonsil Stone/Caught by Amygdala, you cannot proceed to the second floor straight away. You will be able to access the 2nd floor, and then the Nightmare of Mensis, via other means.  Arriving at the Lecture Building (1st floor) first doesn't cause any problems or restrict access to other areas.

Comment: So there not unavailable for the whole game? There's one point  I still can get there? I don't want to miss anything in the game

Comment: @user1916 you won't miss anything.  I'll clarify my answer.